# ListView scrollbar flickering

Tags: c, winapi, listview

I am coding my first program with GUI using only pure WinAPI. But I faced some strange problem.

There are 2 ListView elements on the form to output some values. When scrollbar appears on second ListView, all child objects on the form disappears. And scrollbar of that ListView is flickering. And when I push on that ListView all get back to normal. I don't know what to do.

But this problem applies only to the second ListView element, hListViewCh on the form. There is all ok with the first element.

Here is the code:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &Rect);

    h_Chk1 = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Graphic"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
             Rect.right - 550, 
     300  + 10, 
     100, 
     20,
     hWnd, (HMENU)0xCB01, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
        h_Chk2 = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Diagram"),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_CHECKBOX,
             Rect.right - 550, 
     300  + 35, 
     100, 
     20,
     hWnd, (HMENU)0xCB02, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
        CheckDlgButton(hWnd, 0xCB01, BST_UNCHECKED);
    CheckDlgButton(hWnd, 0xCB02, BST_UNCHECKED);

            hListViewCh = CreateWindow(
                WC_LISTVIEW, 
                _T("MyList"),
                LVS_REPORT|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
                Rect.right - 265,
                377,
                     250,
                200,
                hWnd, (HMENU)listViewCh, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
            //--
            LVCOLUMN lvColumn = {0};
            lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT|LVCF_WIDTH|LVCF_TEXT;
            lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_CENTER;
            lvColumn.pszText = "№";
            lvColumn.cx = 30;
            ListView_InsertColumn(hListViewCh, 0, &lvColumn);
            lvColumn.pszText = "Property";
            lvColumn.cx = 70;
            ListView_InsertColumn(hListViewCh, 1, &lvColumn);
            lvColumn.pszText = "Value";
            lvColumn.cx = 120;
            ListView_InsertColumn(hListViewCh, 2, &lvColumn);
            //--
         hListView = CreateWindow(
          WC_LISTVIEW,
          _T("Set of variate values"),
          LVS_REPORT|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
          Rect.right - 550,
          Rect.top   +  15,
          535,
          275,
          hWnd,
          (HMENU)listView,
          (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
          NULL);
            //--
            lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT|LVCF_WIDTH|LVCF_TEXT;
            lvColumn.pszText = "No";
            lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_CENTER;
            lvColumn.cx = 43;
                            ListView_InsertColumn(hListView, 0, &lvColumn);
            //--
            lvColumn.pszText = "[ a[i-1]      ,         a[i] )";
            lvColumn.cx = 151;
            ListView_InsertColumn(hListView, 1, &lvColumn);
            //--
            lvColumn.pszText = "xi";
            lvColumn.cx = 85;
            ListView_InsertColumn(hListView, 2, &lvColumn);
            //--
            lvColumn.pszText = "ni";
            ListView_InsertColumn(hListView, 3, &lvColumn);
            //--
            lvColumn.pszText = "V";
            ListView_InsertColumn(hListView, 4, &lvColumn);
            //--
            lvColumn.pszText = "EV";
            ListView_InsertColumn(hListView, 5, &lvColumn);
            break;
}
```

There is some redraw functions in WM_PAINT to make ListViews move with a window on maximizing.

```
        //-- LISTVIEW POSITION
        SetWindowPos(hListViewCh, NULL,\
                            Rect.right - 265,
                            312,
                            250,
                            200,
                            SWP_NOSIZE);
        //-- LISTVIEW POSITION
        SetWindowPos(hListView, NULL,\
                            Rect.right - 550,\
                            Rect.top   +  15,\
                            535,\
                            340,\
                            SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOZORDER);
        //--
```

Answer (score 3):

Resizing child windows in a WM_PAINT is simply wrong and I suspect this to be a big part of your problems.

The code to position the child windows should be run in response to the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message.

Comment: @adrian if you choose that route you also need to handle WM_MOVE.

Comment: I've tried to do as you say, but it didn't help - scroll flickers after every redraw.

Comment: have you tried removing all code from your window procedure and using the default handling?

Comment: ListView were filling in WM_PAINT, and it was in infinite update state, that was the reason. Thank you for support!

Comment: that's just another version of the same problem. WM_PAINT is for painting only. You must do nothing else especially not anything that causes more WM_PAINT messages.

Comment: @David Heffernan:  No, you don't need to handle WM_MOVE for child windows.  They should come along for the ride.